# JQuery como monitorar troca de valores?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um radio button:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" id="monitor" style="display:none;">
```

Aqui altero o valor dele, e gostaria de que fosse disparado um alarme:

```
$(function(){

        $("#umItemQualquer").click(function(){

            alert("antes da mudança " + $("#monitor").val())

            $("#monitor").val(2); //Alterando valor do radio

            alert("depois da mudança " + $("#monitor").val())

        });

        // Essa função não deveria ser ativada?
        $("#monitor").change(function(){
            alert("agora o bicho vai pegar!")
            dispararAlarme();
        });

    });
```

Comment: De acordo com seu código, toda vez que você alterar o valor do radio será executado o alert e a função dispararAlarme.

Mas qual seria o objetivo disso, para um radio que está oculto (display:none) na página?

Comment: Uma gambi que quero fazer aqui, rsrsrs...

Comment: Com "display:none" o change nunca será acionado, pois não tem como fazer o elemento perder o foco se ele nem aparece na tela... ;)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues foi respondida sua dúvida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O evento `change` só é chamado quando o campo perde foco e teve seu valor modificado. Mais informações **[aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)**.

Quando você altera o valor por comando, ele possui o valor modificado, porém não tem a perda de foco, por isso o `change` não é chamado.

Se quiser forçar a ativação dele manualmente é só colocar

```
$("#monitor").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo, mas não intendi bem a questão do trigger

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues trigger (tradução: gatilho) dispara o evento `change` do `#monitor`

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Você pode utilizar `$("#monitor").change();` se preferir. O `trigger` é apenas um atalho.